# pmd plugin is not available in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pmd

pmd plugin is not available in jenkins
[image: pmd plugin is not available in jenkins]

Neither it is available on [jenkins plugins page](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pmd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching the Jenkins plugin site reveals nothing as observed.

But if you look in [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pmd-plugin), it shows the following:

> This plugin reached end-of-life.
>
> All functionality has been integrated into the [Warnings Next
> Generation Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin)
> and the [Static Analysis Model and Parsers
> Library](https://github.com/jenkinsci/analysis-model).

If you look on the [Jenkins plugins site](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pmd/), it shows "forbidden". That suggests it's been pulled and its use discouraged.

Instead, install the [Warnings Next Generation Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin) (needs some latest dependencies).

In your job, add a build-step *"Records compiler warnings and static analysis results"*.
Choose "Static Analysis Tool | Tool" **[  PMD ]**. The default intake is "`'**/pmd.xml'`".

The [plugin's](https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings-ng/) [main page](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin) gives an overview and notes support for more than hundred [report formats](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/SUPPORTED-FORMATS.md). There is [additional documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md) describing all the extra features.

---

ps: Perhaps Jenkins needs a better mechanism ([WEBSITE-764:Deprecated plugin handling - UX](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/WEBSITE-764)) to handle removed plugins?

Comment: how to 'Publish PMD analysis results' then?

Comment: The [Documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/warnings-ng-plugin/blob/master/doc/Documentation.md) has lots of examples, including PMD specific references.